# Target Device->"GPU" Not Working For Machine Learning: LibraryFunction error

Tags: parallelization, machine-learning, neural-networks, cudalink, cuda

I'm running Wolfram Desktop version 13.2.1, and after downloading Visual Studio, Nvidia Toolkit version 12.1 and 11.2, and verifying that

```
Needs["CUDALink`"]
CUDAInformation[]
{1 -> {"Name" -> "Quadro M4000", "Clock Rate" -> 772500, 
"Compute Capabilities" -> 5.2, "GPU Overlap" -> 1, 
"Maximum Block Dimensions" -> {1024, 1024, 64}, 
"Maximum Grid Dimensions" -> {2147483647, 65535, 65535}, 
"Maximum Threads Per Block" -> 1024, 
"Maximum Shared Memory Per Block" -> 49152, 
"Total Constant Memory" -> 65536, "Warp Size" -> 32, 
"Maximum Pitch" -> 2147483647, 
"Maximum Registers Per Block" -> 65536, "Texture Alignment" -> 512,
"Multiprocessor Count" -> 13, "Core Count" -> 1664, 
"Execution Timeout" -> 1, "Integrated" -> False, 
"Can Map Host Memory" -> True, "Compute Mode" -> "Default", 
"Texture1D Width" -> 65536, "Texture2D Width" -> 65536, 
"Texture2D Height" -> 65536, "Texture3D Width" -> 4096, 
"Texture3D Height" -> 4096, "Texture3D Depth" -> 4096, 
"Texture2D Array Width" -> 16384, 
"Texture2D Array Height" -> 16384, 
"Texture2D Array Slices" -> 2048, "Surface Alignment" -> 512, 
"Concurrent Kernels" -> True, "ECC Enabled" -> False, 
"TCC Enabled" -> False, "Total Memory" -> 8589672448}}
 
CUDADriverVersion[]
531.14
```

I try to run this simple code so I can see first hand how these CUDA cores allow faster training of neural networks,

```
trainingset = {1 -> 1.3, 2 -> 2.4, 3 -> 4.4, 4 -> 5.1, 6 -> 7.3};
p = Predict[trainingset, Method -> "NeuralNetwork", TargetDevice -> "GPU"]
```

And I get a bunch of errors.

First this pops up [image]

Then this errors show up after I click okay

LibraryFunction::load: The library C:\Users\dirac\AppData\Roaming\WolframDesktop\Paclets\Repository\MXNetResources-WIN64-13.2.11\LibraryResources\Windows-x86-64\cublas64_11.dll cannot be loaded.

Any help getting my CUDA cores working for me in Mathematica's ML and deep learning department would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is the cublas...dll in the folder given by the error message?

Comment: cublas64_11.dll is there, yes.

Comment: The exact code works for me. Mathematica did tell me that `TargetDevice -> GPU` required me to exit and restart the current session. But after the restart, the code worked for me.

Comment: @Shredderroy if you are running the same version as me on windows, would it be possible to send me a copy of your cublas64_11.dll file so I can replace mine? Perhaps my version of it is corrupt.

Comment: Actually, my `AppData\Roaming` does not contain `WolframDesktop`, only `Wolfram`. And there is no `Paclets` under `AppData\Roaming\Wolfram`. Let me check where it is hiding.

Comment: Okay, I have found it. It was under `Mathematica`, not `WolframDesktop`. See if you can download it here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eMc6cSQpmtduZWbtX7WPfynkzgTNk1o0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Shredderroy I downloaded it, but sadly it didn't work. What version of Nvida ToolKit are you using.

Comment: It looks like I installed it from `cuda_11.7.0_516.01_windows.exe`.

Comment: You mentioned both toolkit of Nvidia 12.1 and 11.2 . Any reason for that? May be something went wrong there during installation.